# How to replace "a:1:{s:10:"a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}";" with "a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}"?

Tags: sql, wordpress

Can anyone help to tell me how to do the SQL statement to replace the special characters below?

My goal is to replace

> a:1:{s:10:"a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}";"

with

> "a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}"?"

```
UPDATE `wp_buddypress_dev`.`wp_usermeta` 
SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}') 
WHERE `meta_value` = 'a:1:{s:10:"a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}";';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you declare more clearly: 1. You have a column that have value `ab`, you want to replace exactly value like that to `abcxyz` Or 2. You have column that have value `abcabx`, you want to replace all `ab` in that string to `mn` so it  will be `mncmnx`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean simply:

```
UPDATE `wp_buddypress_dev`.`wp_usermeta` 
SET `meta_value` = REPLACE(`meta_value`, 'a:1:{s:10:"a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}";', 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}') 
WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '%a:1:{s:10:"a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}";%';
```

I replaced the equal operator with a `like`, otherwise the `replace` wouldn't make sense, you could just set it to the new value.

Comment: Thanks! i tried with your solution, but the special character won't be inserted correctly. any suggestions for that?

Comment: @user1933891 I don't understand what you mean. What special character?

Comment: Thanks! it is working now. i have a typo before, now it is working.